# What open operator to use with jsons

Tags: python, json

```
with open(path, "rb") as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
        DO SOME STUFF WITH THE DATA
        print(data)
        json.dump(data, json_file)
```

What am I doing wrong? It always shows an error on save or opening the json file (its a dict where i change values in the function)

Comment: You're opening the file in *reading* mode, so you can't write to it.

Comment: The `r+` mode opens the file for both reading and writing.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are facing is due to the file being opened in binary mode `"rb"` and trying to read the JSON content using `json.load`, which expects the file to be a text file, not binary. When you try to dump the JSON data back into the file, you encounter the same issue because you're attempting to write text data to a file opened in binary mode.

Here's the corrected code:

```py
with open(path, "r") as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

# DO SOME STUFF WITH THE DATA

with open(path, "w") as json_file:
    json.dump(data, json_file)

print(data)
```

Here, I've changed the mode from `"rb"` to `"r"` for reading the file and added a separate block with `"w"` for writing the modified data back to the file. This should resolve the error you were encountering.